# Showing that if $Hg^{−1}_1 = Hg^{−1}_2$, then $g_1H = g_2H.$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

$Hg^{−1}_1 = Hg^{−1}_2 \implies g_1H = g_2H $

I have a really quick question. I was doing some Group theory exercises, for this particular question I couldn't understand the proof:

> "Since $Hg^{-1}_1=Hg^{-1}_2$ there is an $h \in H$ with $g^{-1}_1=hg^{-1}_2$ and $g_2=g_1h$."

How do I know that? I couldn't understand the equality and how $g_2=g_1h$. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of $Hg$, with $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $g$ an element of $G$ ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put up the definition but yours is correct

Comment: You know that $g_1^{-1}=hg_2^{-1}$. Multiply both sides by $g_2$ from the right side, then multiply both sides by $g_1$ from the left side.

Comment: How do I know that  $^{-1}_1=ℎ^{−1}_2$. I can't understand how multiplying the $g_1$ with a specific element h makes it equal to $g_2$. Is there always such an element?

Comment: What does it mean that $Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$? We have $g_1^{-1}=eg_1^{-1}\in Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$. Hence there is an element $h\in H$ such that $g_1^{-1}=hg_2^{-1}$.

Comment: I get that how $g^{-1}_1$ is in $g_1$. But is there a proof for there's always an element $h \in H$ st $g^{-1}_1=hg^{-1}_2$? From the examples I can see that it is correct, but I don't understand the intuition behind why this should be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

$Hg_1^{-1} = Hg_2^{-1}, \tag 1$

we choose

$e \in H, \tag 2$

where $e$ is the identity element of $G$; we know (2) binds since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$; then

$g_1^{-1} = eg_1^{-1} \in Hg_2^{-1} \tag 3$

by virtue of (1); thus

$\exists h \in H, \; g_1^{-1} = hg_2^{-1}; \tag 4$

this yields

$e = g_1g_1^{-1} = g_1hg_2^{-1}, \tag 5$

and *this* further yields

$g_2 = eg_2 = (g_1hg_2^{-1})g_2 = g_1h(g_2^{-1}g_2) = g_1he = g_1h, \tag 6$

the desired relation 'twixt $g_1$, $g_2$, and $h$.

Comment: The part that I dont understand is exactly part (4). How can we know from the equality that there's an h that makes them equal. I can't get the intuition, maybe I am slow.

Comment: The right coset $Hg_2^{-1}$ is precisely the set $\{kg_2^{-1}, \; k \in H \}$; that is, it consists precisely of every element of $H$ right multiplied by $g_2^{-1}$.  Since $g_1^{-1}$ is one  of these elements, (4) must bind for *some* $h \in H$..  Does this help?  Let me know .. . .

Answer (score 2):

Since $Hg^{-1}_1=Hg^{-1}_2$, there exist $h_1, h_2\in H$ such that $h_1g^{-1}_1=h_2g^{-1}_2$. Cancel $h_1$ to get $g^{-1}_1=(h_1^{-1}h_2)g^{-1}_2$ and note that $h:=h_1^{-1}h_2\in H$. Cancel $g^{-1}_1$ on the left and multiply by $g_2$ on the right. Then $g_2=g_1h$.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if you multiply $H$ by an element of it, then it remains itself. So, $g_1 h H = g_1 H$

Answer (score 1):

$g_1^{-1}$ belongs to $Hg_1^{-1}$ since it is expressible as $eg_1^{-1}$ (as $e \in H$).  But $Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$ so $g_1^{-1}$ must be expressible as $g_1^{-1}=hg_2^{-1}$ for some $h \in H$.  Solve for $g_2$ (right multiply by $g_2$, left multiply by $g_1$) to get $g_2=g_1h$, as claimed.

Comment: Why the downvote?  What's missing or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X^{-1} = \{ x^{-1} : x \in X \}$. Then
$$
Hg^{−1}_1 = Hg^{−1}_2
\implies 
(Hg^{−1}_1)^{−1} = (Hg^{−1}_2)^{−1}
\implies
g_1 H^{−1} = g_2 H^{−1}
\implies
g_1 H = g_2 H
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $k=h_1g_1^{-1}=h_2g_2^{-1}$ (so $k\in Hg_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}$) then what form does $k^{-1}$ have?

Comment: $k^{-1}=g_1h^{-1}_1=g_2h^{-1}_2$ ?

Comment: Exactly. So as $h_1, h_2\in H$ what can you conclude?